# Get the table name as dynamically in ssis

Tags: ssis-2012

I have a table in that table i'm inserting all my TableNames of that database.
Now I need to pass this table name to OLEDB source DYNAMICALLY   from my main table one by one 
Is this possible to to pass the table name as dynamically in OLEDB source.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are then going to run some SQL against the stored table name?

You'll need to approach this differently and run what you are trying within a SQL task.

If not, give us some more information about exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Jim, I explain clearly about my task for example from sys.tables I need to get the  table names and pass it in OLEDB source or destination one by one.is this possible.

Comment: Yes, but you don't explain what you trying to achieve.

Why are you loading the table names into a table?

Comment: In data flow task in source (dev sever) and destination (test sever)  i need to get the table name and matching both the  tables if  any insert,update, delete it need to done. This is my requirement